# Can't login with new LDAP user on Alfresco via CMIS

Tags: ldap, mule, alfresco, cmis

I have an Alfresco Enterprise edition version 5.1.2 running on Java version 1.8.0-65 that uses external LDAP server (OpenLDAP) as a directory server.
Alfresco synchronizes with the LDAP server on startup, and is configured with synchronization settings `Auto Create People On Login` and `Sync Changes Only`on.

When a new user is created on the LDAP server, and I try to log in with that user trough CMIS, I get an error with the following stacktrace:

```
The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.</u></p><p><b>exception</b> <pre>java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: currentUser is a mandatory parameter
org.alfresco.util.ParameterCheck.mandatoryString(ParameterCheck.java:58)
org.alfresco.module.org_alfresco_module_rm.securitymarks.SecurityClearanceServiceImpl.isClearedFor(SecurityClearanceServiceImpl.java:120)
org.alfresco.module.org_alfresco_module_rm.securitymarks.permission.SecurityMarksPermissionPreProcessor.process(SecurityMarksPermissionPreProcessor.java:115)
org.alfresco.repo.security.permissions.impl.ExtendedPermissionServiceImpl.hasPermission(ExtendedPermissionServiceImpl.java:194)
org.alfresco.repo.security.person.PersonServiceImpl.personExists(PersonServiceImpl.java:530)
org.alfresco.repo.security.sync.ChainingUserRegistrySynchronizer.createMissingPerson(ChainingUserRegistrySynchronizer.java:862)
org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.SubsystemProxyFactory$1.invoke(SubsystemProxyFactory.java:79)
org.alfresco.repo.security.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationComponent$FixCurrentUserCallback$1.doWork(AbstractAuthenticationComponent.java:550)
org.alfresco.repo.security.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationComponent$FixCurrentUserCallback$1.doWork(AbstractAuthenticationComponent.java:1)
org.alfresco.repo.tenant.TenantUtil.runAsWork(TenantUtil.java:126)
org.alfresco.repo.tenant.TenantUtil.runAsTenant(TenantUtil.java:95)
org.alfresco.repo.tenant.TenantUtil$1.doWork(TenantUtil.java:69)
org.alfresco.repo.security.authentication.AuthenticationUtil.runAs(AuthenticationUtil.java:555)
org.alfresco.repo.tenant.TenantUtil.runAsUserTenant(TenantUtil.java:65)
org.alfresco.repo.tenant.TenantUtil.runAsSystemTenant(TenantUtil.java:119)
org.alfresco.repo.security.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationComponent$FixCurrentUserCallback.execute(AbstractAuthenticationComponent.java:539)
org.alfresco.repo.security.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationComponent$FixCurrentUserCallback.execute(AbstractAuthenticationComponent.java:1)
org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:464)
org.alfresco.repo.security.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationComponent.setCurrentUser(AbstractAuthenticationComponent.java:234)
org.alfresco.repo.security.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationComponent.setCurrentUser(AbstractAuthenticationComponent.java:203)
org.alfresco.enterprise.repo.authorization.AuthorizationInterceptor.checkAuthorization(AuthorizationInterceptor.java:115)
org.alfresco.enterprise.repo.authorization.AuthorizationInterceptor.invoke(AuthorizationInterceptor.java:63)
org.alfresco.repo.security.authentication.AbstractChainingAuthenticationComponent.setCurrentUser(AbstractChainingAuthenticationComponent.java:188)
org.alfresco.repo.webdav.auth.BaseAuthenticationFilter.getSessionUser(BaseAuthenticationFilter.java:260)
org.alfresco.repo.webdav.auth.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:121)
org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChainingSubsystemProxyFactory$1.invoke(ChainingSubsystemProxyFactory.java:132)
org.alfresco.repo.web.filter.beans.BeanProxyFilter.doFilter(BeanProxyFilter.java:89)
org.alfresco.web.app.servlet.CmisSecurityContextCleanerFilter.doFilter(CmisSecurityContextCleanerFilter.java:56)
org.alfresco.web.app.servlet.GlobalLocalizationFilter.doFilter(GlobalLocalizationFilter.java:68)
```

I omitted the lines from the proxy classes and interceptors from the stacktrace for better readability.

The same user is able to login to Alfresco via the web interface, and on subsequent attempts to access Alfresco via CMIS with the same user, Alfresco returns properly.

I have analyzed the stacktrace and the Alfresco sources that are available, and ultimately it fails at `org.alfresco.repo.security.authentication.AuthenticationUtil.getRunAsUser()` which returns `null` and the validation fails with the `currentUser is a mandatory parameter` message.

My expectation is that it should be possible to log in on Alfresco via CMIS since the user already exists, and it is possible to log in with that user on Alfresco via the web interface.

My question is if there are some Alfresco settings that should be updated in order to make this work, if there are additional parameters that should be set to the CMIS request, or it is not possible at all?

Comment: 1) What binding are you using? (i.e., what does your endpoint URL look like?) Atompub? Browser? Web services? See this: https://community.alfresco.com/docs/DOC-5527-cmis

Comment: Also, if you try connecting with Apache Chemistry's CMIS workbench, does it succeed with that user? http://chemistry.apache.org/java/developing/tools/dev-tools-workbench.html

Comment: The library that executes the GET request calling the Alfresco endpoint is `chemistry-opencmis-client-bindings-0.9.0`, and the call is executed from the `AbstractAtomPubService#read(UrlBuilder url)` method, so I guess that would be Atompub.

Comment: I've lost track of the status, but Alfresco at some point broke something here, I know I've dealt with similar issue before. You can track this through JIRA too.

https://community.alfresco.com/thread/201247-sso-and-cmis

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce this on Alfresco Community Edition 5.1.f on Linux authenticating against OpenLDAP.

The test steps are:

1. Validate that authentication works for LDAP users.
2. Validate that Apache Chemistry CMIS Workbench can authenticate using LDAP users.
3. Add a new user to LDAP (tuser4).
4. Validate that I can log in to Share via the new user (tuser4).
5. Add another new user to LDAP (tuser5).
6. Validate that I can log in via CMIS Workbench using the new user (tuser5).

All of these steps pass.

The CMIS service URL I am using in Workbench is: http://alfresco.local:8080/alfresco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.1/atom

Make sure yours matches that. It could be the issue.

If your service URL matches, please provide the code you are using to get a session.